# Get the type of the class in a static function c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, static-members

I have this piece of code:

```
struct Type{
  const char* name;
  // other stuff
};

template <class T>
class Base{
 public:
    // some other functions
    static const Type *Get_Type(){
       /* Get the STATIC type of the class and make a new Type object */
    virtual const Type *My_Type();
};
```

***EDIT:***

I want to implement both member functions, Get_Type() and My_Type().
Every derived class that inherits from Base< T> inherits like this Base< Derived >.

I don't have access to any of the Derived classes and I can't change the declaration for Get_Type() and My_Type(), everything else, however, is permitted.

Get_Type() - should be implemented to return the Type of the class that called it.

My_Type - should be implemented to return the dynamic class type of the calling object.

for example:

```
class Derived1: public Base<Derived1> {
 public:
    Derived1() {}
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1 , public Base<Derived2> {
 public:
    Derived2() {}
};

int main() {
    Derived1* b= new Derived2();
    Derived2::Get_Type(); // should return a struct Type with name=Derived2
    b->My_Type(); // should return a struct Type with name=Derived2
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1) How can I know the type of the calling class, inside the body of the static function Get_Type?

2) How can I get the dynamic type of the object (`this`) inside the body of My_Type() ?

Comment: You cannot do this with a static function.

Comment: is there a way around it? i can change Base but not any of the derived classes

Comment: You can use a normal member function in the base class and `typeid(this)` to catch the actual class name.

Comment: You mean a non-static member function? I thought I can't call a non-static from a static

Comment: Why do you need a static function? I don't get your point.

Comment: I'm studying OOP and Base class was given to me along with the 2 member functions that are in the code. I can implement them and add more member functions/variables but I can't change the declaration.

Comment: 'Inherited static function' is a contradiction in terms. Unclear what you're asking, or why. RTTI already does all this.

Comment: @EJP I'm still studying, sorry if I had contradicting terms. What is it you don't understand about my question though?

Comment: @Loay - I don't understand what do you mean with "should return Derived2"; do you mean that `Get_Type()` (and `My_Type()` too) should return a (pointer to a) struct of type `Type`? With `name` pointing to a string with "Derived2"? Or do you mean than `Get_Type()` should return a (pointer to an) object of type `Derived2`?

Comment: @max66 I mean it should return a pointer to a struct of a type Type with name pointing to a string with "Derived2"

Comment: @Loay - ok; and the string "Derived2" should be member of `Derived2` class (or equipped, in some way, by `Derived2`) or do you want determined, in same way, by the language?

Comment: I want it determined by the language

Answer (score 1):

There are no virtual statics in C++. The closest you can get is:

- Make it a virtual member function
- Have an intermediate BaseGetTypeImpl template class that inherits from Base
- Let BaseGetTypeImpl implement Get_Type() using T's type
- When declaring derived, inherit from BaseGetTypeImpl

This is called CRTP.

An alternative to this - since you only need the type - would be a traits template class that's declared *outside* of base (i.e., global).

Comment: Derived classes inherit from Base directly and I can't make the intermediate class (nor change function's declaration) so I guess the first solution won't work for me.
How can I use the traits template class though?

Comment: First things first. It's not clear for me now whether you have `Base` or `Base<Derived>` as your base class...

Comment: If it's Base<Derived>, you could just make My_Type() a non-virtual static and say Derived::My_Type() in Base<>.

Comment: so why virtual? why not just `static const Type *Get_Type(){ return Derived::Get_Type(); };`?

Comment: Get_Type isn't virtual, it's static const Type *Get_Type. As for static const Type *Get_Type(){ return Derived::Get_Type(); }; wouldn't it work if Derived class doesn't overload the function?

Comment: In the edit, you're writing multiple inheritance.. This is not very practical as you now have the same method names in two base classes and need to qualify the one you'd like to use... Also, despite you say you don't have control over your derived classes, you've changed their definition quite much.. What's the exact problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: * Every class that inherits from Base< T >, Inherits like this: public Base< Derived >. it can inherit from other classes, as well any class X that inherited from Base< X >. I don't have control over the derived classes, I only put an example of one (others don't have to necessarily be in same format but they have to follow the inheritance rule.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is getting the type from template parameter.
The full definition of Get_Type() would be:

```
template<class T>
const Type *Base<T>::Get_Type() {/* get T's name and construct a Type struct */}
```

And from T you can have the type of the calling class.

As for My_Type(), the definition would be:

```
virtual const Type *My_Type(){
   return this->Get_Type();
}
```

Since c++ uses dynamic binding, the called member function would be the one of the dynamic class of the calling object.